# How to deploy a MDB without an active JMS configuration in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, ejb-3.0

I have the following in my jboss-ejb3.xml (sample one),

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:mdb="urn:resource-adapter-binding"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd
  http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-spec-2_0.xsd
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">


<jboss:enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>TestMdb1</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.Test</ejb-class>
        <messaging-type>com.MessageListener</messaging-type>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>connectionName</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>java:/JCA/xyz</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>               
        </activation-config>                    
    </message-driven>   
</jboss:enterprise-beans>

<assembly-descriptor>
    <mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
        <ejb-name>TestMdb1</ejb-name>
        <mdb:resource-adapter-name>myRar.rar</mdb:resource-adapter-name>
    </mdb:resource-adapter-binding>     
</assembly-descriptor>
```

I want to deploy my application with this jboss-ejb3.xml but the standalone.xml does not specify the connection-definition.

My application fails to deploy without the required connection-definition. I want my application to be deployed and active, without the particular connection-definition.

Comment: Where is the queue/topic located, is it on the same server?  Any reason you do not want to have it in standalone.xml which by the way is not the correct file in the first place, you would need standalone-full.xml to enable JMS/ActiveMQ or are you trying to use standalone.xml and then make use of the resource adapter to handle the JMS implementation?

Comment: Do you have the actual error message and/or stack-trace involved here? It looks to me like you're trying to use custom JCA resource adapter with your MDB (which shouldn't be a problem, in general). Is your JCA RA being deployed properly?